# Calculate List Height By adding new listitems to the list

Tags: html, css, listview

Assume : I have a List call Category(height is 300px). There are already 5 Items on it.

So i need is, if i add another category item through backend, that new item should auto set to new height. (See the example to clear bit more)

Example : I have 5 category item. And List height is 300px. So this case each list item will set height as (300/5) 60px. If i add new category item then height should be set to (300/6) 50px.

**list**

```
<div class="categories">
  <ul>
    <h3>Categories</h3>
      <?php
      foreach ($cat as $new_cat){
       ?>
          <li class="cat_list"><a href="#"><?php echo $new_cat['cat_item'];?></a></li>
      <?php
      }
      ?>

  </ul>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
  .categories{
    border:1px solid #EEE;
    height: 434px;
    max-height: 434px;
}
.categories h3{
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:10px;
    background:#B81D22;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: 'ambleregular';    
}
.categories li a{
    display:block;
    font-size:0.8em;
    padding:8px 15px;
    color: #9C9C9C;
    font-family: 'ambleregular';
    margin:0 20px;
    background:url(../images/drop_arrow.png) no-repeat 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    text-transform:uppercase;   
}
.categories li:last-child a{
    border:none;
}
.categories li a:hover{
    color:#B81D22;
}
```

how can i mange this??

Comment: can you share a code or fiddle?

Comment: @GaneshSalunkhe there is no existing code. List item only created and  no css code for that. I need idea or suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by jquery

**Html**

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

**Css**

```
.list {
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

**Script**

```
var listCount = $(".list").find("li").length;
var listHeight = $(".list").height();
$(".list li").height(listHeight / listCount);
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2085oj3m/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery, and call following function after you add new item through backend:

```
function changeHeight(){
   var _count = $('#category option').size();
   var _newHeight = 20*_count;
   $('#category').css('height',_newHeight+'px');
}
```

Here, 'category' is id of your list(I suppose you are using 'select' tag with multiple option as a list). You can use _newHeight to calculate as per your need.